# javascript memory problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, memory-leaks, jwplayer

i have some problems with my site. it eats ram like a monster.
javascript causes that but i don't know what to do.

i use jquery framework and jwplayer(+some listeners)

how can I detect which code causes that?

Comment: I've never seen these kinds of problems with jQuery or jQuery UI, unless you have a boatload of code, or you've got a recursive call somewhere.

Comment: FYI: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ieleak/  a memory leak detector for IE

Comment: this program reports a simple div as a leak. like <div id=x></div> to get data from ajax. if ajax would cause leak the program would point to related function right?

Answer (score 1):

Using firefox plugin like [Leak Monitor](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/2490/) helps you find issues. It can help you find memory leaks in extension scripts too.